# networking and openvpn does not work with hibernate-script

Tags: networking, ubuntu, openvpn, hibernation

after suspend-to-disk via hibernate-script I can't reach the internet. That happens since I use openvpn. Stopping network, restarting openvpn and the starting the network solves the problem. I want to configure hibernate-script to do this automatically. I tried setting `RestartServices networking openvpn` in `hibernate.conf` but this doesn't work (I think this first restarts networking and then openvpn but I need the openvpn restart in between).

Kind regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As hibernate.conf doesn't seem to work](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation#Suspend_and_hibernate_configuration_in_Debian_Lenny) I did this :

```
echo 'case "${1}" in
    hibernate|suspend)
    sudo service openvpn restart
    ;;
esac' | sudo tee /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_restart-openvpn
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_restart-openvpn
```

This create a script called "20_restart-openvpn" (you can change the name of the script) and make it executable. I hope this can help you too ...